# Concatenate variable in a query - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, concatenation

My question is basic.

I am creating a stored procedure and have it the following variable:

```
@ConcatenarClausulaWhere
```

During the execution of the procedure, several conditions are concatenated in this variable to be inserted after the WHERE:

```
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE1
WHERE indStatus = 'True'
AND (Description LIKE '%' + @ STRING + '%')
```

My intention was to do something like:

```
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE1 The
WHERE indStatus = 'True'
AND (Description LIKE '%' + @ STRING + '%') + @ ConcatenarClausulaWhere
```

But, it is not possible. Why?

I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 3):

You need dynamic SQL to append a `WHERE` clause to a query. A `SELECT` statement is not just a string. You also need to be very wary of SQL injection here. How are you validating what users are entering into this where clause parameter?

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT ID FROM dbo.TABLE1 
  WHERE indStatus = ''True'' AND (Description LIKE @String)'
  + @ConcatenarClausulaWhere;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@String NVARCHAR(MAX)', N'%' + @STRING + '%';
```